# How to make js only affect element of concern?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, click

I have this super easy JS that does one thing; namely toggles an `open` class on a specific element in the page. Problem is that I have 4 repetitions of both the `.clickSlide` element and the `.sub_menu` element and when I click one of the elements to trigger the code all elements gets the `open` class. Only the element of concern, out of the 4, should get the `open` class.

My best guess is I am missing some sort of `this` in the JS. But I am open to solutions on this one!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickSlide").click(function() {
    $(".sub_menu").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ht_course_one">
  <ul class="select-menu dropdown">
    <li class="clickSlide">
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="ht_course_two">
  <ul class="select-menu">
    <li class="clickSlide">
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="ht_course_three">
  <ul class="select-menu">
    <li class="clickSlide">
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="ht_course_four">
  <ul class="select-menu">
    <li class="clickSlide">
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How you traverse from `this` to the target element depends on the structure of the markup.  Please include the HTML as well for a runnable [mcve].

Comment: As requested the HTML is now added to the question!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution (based on Anass Kartit answer) was this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickSlide").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".sub_menu").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```